# I have waited for 2days now my transaction not confirmed yet

Tags: bitcoind

I have made 2 transaction but not confirmed yet
Blockchain: a68891b83177797c932873e3e5ff601bcea6e28b1cdbeb5a038dc0939c8371e0,
543c5f4612398c0b783fd3959a3390850a584c79a6c4fbe80bef88ebf455878f pls i need to be fix urgently

Answer (score 1):

I can see that one of the transactions has been confirmed, so your problem is half solved. For the other transaction you just need to wait. If you're experienced enough you might as well want to [rebroadcast the stuck transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22693/is-it-possible-to-add-a-miners-fee-after-you-send-your-bitcoins) with a higher fee.

## The problem

The transaction fee you have included in both transactions is way too low. At the current state of the bitcoin network, there is not enough room in blocks to fit all of the transactions, so the miners pick only the transactions with higher fees.

## Prevent from happening again

If you require your transactions to be confirmed in a short period of time, then you need to include a much higher miner fee. You can use the following site as a guide as to what the fee should be:
https://bitcoinfees.21.co/